# How to receive data from XMLHttpRequest in chome extension via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I wanna to send request form a webpage to chrome extension, and then in chrome extenison receive data and read data, is there any way to this?

Ex:
In doman www.nope.com/sendRequest.html will sent data to chrome extension via url chrome-extension://xxxxxxx/getData.htm?isToken=abc, and then extension will receive and can read data "isToken".

Here is my code in sendRequest.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendRequest() {
        document.write("Sending request");
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", "chrome-extension://xxxxxxxxxx/getData.htm?isToken=abc", true);
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    alert(req.responseText);
                    document.write("OK");
                }
            }
        };
        req.send();
    }
</script>
```

And in chrome extension file getData.htm, how can I get data?

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: what type of data are you sending? Could you pass it through as a JSON encoded string, via GET? JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() may be of use to you. :)

The following may be useful as a guide for accessing that POST/GET data. :) )

As far as I am aware, this is best done using some form of server side scripting. You could use window.location.search in JS, and split the string and perform the necessary functions, but I think server-side scripting may work best. :)

An example of a JS implementation could be as follows:

```
   var url = window.location.search;
   var params = url.substr(url.IndexOf("?") - 1, 30);
```

This would grab the parameters (starting at ? (inclusive), and continue for 30 chars. You could also use something like `var params = url.substr(url.IndexOf("?") - 1, url.length);` to get the whole parameters list.

How you use this from then on, is up to you, but you could pass it through a switch() or whatever you need. :)

Obviously, this being a chrome extension would limit your options regarding any server-side processing. :/

Edit: The above would go in getData.htm. :)